# Kaobook - Changing page & text width?

Tags: formatting, packages, templates, textwidth

Being a complete newcomer to LaTeX, I decided to get acquainted with kaobook for a project I'm working on.

I got the hang of how it works, but I don't know for the life of me how I'd change the page width and text width in order to get wider pages that'll fit more text into them.

All of this, of course, without ruining the margins and the elaborate formatting dependencies that exist within kaobook.

Is anyone here familiar with this?

Comment: It is possible; but the margins, if you take a look, are already narrow. This class is designed for material in the margin to be used. If you don't use material in the margin, it misses the point.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for the reply. I think you misunderstood what I wanted to say: I want to keep the margins, but I just want the overall page to be wider (thereby making the text width wider). How would I go about doing that?

Comment: See if my answer below meets your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The text and margin width in kaobook is regulated by these two commands: `\marginlayout` for the main body; `\widelayout` for the front and back matter. These commands are automatically called and that is likely the reason why you couldn't change the textwidth, because these commands may have been overwriting your own changes. Try with the following redefinitions:

```
\renewcommand{\marginlayout}{%
    \newgeometry{
        top=27.4mm,
        bottom=27.4mm,
        inner=4.8mm,
        textwidth=137mm,
        marginparsep=8.2mm,
        marginparwidth=49.4mm,
        includemp
    }%
}

\renewcommand{\widelayout}{%
    \newgeometry{
        top=27.4mm,
        bottom=27.4mm,
        inner=4.8mm,
        outer=4.8mm,
        marginparsep=0mm,
        marginparwidth=0mm,
        ignoremp
    }%
}
```

(Note that, depending on your preferences, you may also want to change the inner and outer margin sizes)

If you redefine these commands, you may also have to suppress the lines reading `\KOMAoptions{twoside=semi}` and `\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}`, otherwise the wide layout will not work properly. Sorry, but I don't know why this happens; I will be working on a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the text block width, you can try changing the `geometry` package settings. According to `kao.sty`, the defaults for this class are:

```
\RequirePackage[
a4paper,
bottom=27.4mm,
inner=24.8mm,
textwidth=107mm,
marginparsep=8.2mm,
marginparwidth=49.4mm,
includemp
]{geometry}
```

You can change that in the `.sty` file or perhaps in your document with:

```
\geometry{<settings>}
```

Maybe what you want is to change those 2:

```
textwidth=107mm,
marginparwidth=49.4mm,
```

However, the extension of one necessarily implies the reduction of the other.

It's a very nice class.

Comment: Thanks, you putting in your time is much appreciated! I tried fiddling around with this before, but what I found was that despite being able to get the page width to increase to 700pt from the usual 595pt A4 format, I didn't manage to change anything about the text block width. It stayed the same no matter what I did to textwidth=X, same goes for marginparwidth. The extension of one doesn't have to imply the reduction of the other in case I increase the overall paper width of the whole page, which is what I did, yet I can't get the text blocks to widen despite the additional page space I added

Comment: You didn't exactly say that you wanted a larger paper size.  Perhaps you could post a `MWE` (minimum working example) so we can know what you did?